# storing serialized data in postgres by SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building an App by using Flask with Postgress and SQLAlchemy. 
There is a table column where I need to store serialized data (JSON). How do I define the field in the model class?

Can I just use string field for the column?

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from main import app

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Fame (db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "toto"
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column('data', db.JSON)
    creation_date = db.Column('creation_date', db.Date, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

But I got this error:

> AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'JSON'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import [`JSON`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSON) or [`JSONB`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB) from `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql`

Comment: I did do this `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSON` but still got error,

Comment: Ok, I test again and it works. `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql` is the problem.